# losetup mounts disk image as one device. How to loopback the partitions seperately?

Tags: disk-image, loop-device

I have a disk image with 2 partitions. When I do `#losetup -f <file>` only `/dev/loop0` appears. How do I make `/dev/loop0p0` and `/dev/loop0p1` appear? Using `#parted /dev/loop0` it does show the 2 partitions are present. I need the 2 partitions present as seperate devices to chroot into the main partition and set up grub on the esp partition.

```
# sudo losetup -f disk.img
```

Got:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     5G  0 loop 
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 214,5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   8,8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Expected:

```
loop0
├─loop0p0
└─loop1p1
```

Parted showing the partitions do in fact exist:

```
# parted
[ ... ]
(parted) print list,all
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 5369MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  135MB   134MB   fat32        efi   boot, esp
 2      135MB   5368MB  5232MB  ext4         main

[ ... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-P` switch to losetup, like this:

```
losetup -Pf disk.img
```

This will create loop devices for each partition, like `/dev/loop8p3`. Note that partition scanning depends on sector sizes, which are assumed to be 512 by default. If the image was made from something which had different sector sizes, then you need to specify the `--sector-size` switch as well.